# Read file and sum integer

Tags: python, list, integer, sum

I am new to python and trying to read my file and grab the integers and put them into a list and last to get the sum of them.

This is the file:

```
12  234 23  23  3921 4 523 2212 23
212  234 23  23  39
21 4 523 22192 23 2
```

This is how far I have came, tried to print the values and removing the whitespace into a list:

```
reader = open('sumAllExample.txt','r')
data = reader.read()
reader.close()
reader = str.split(data)
print reader
```

The thing I dont get is why it splits some of the integers:

```
['12', '234', '23', '23', '392', '1', '4', '523', '2', '2', '19', '2', '23', '2', '12', '234', '23', '23', '39', '2', '1', '4', '523', '2', '2', '19', '2', '23', '2']
```

Here:

```
'1'
'2'
' '
' '
'2'
'3'
'4'
' '
'2'
'3'
' '
' '
'2'
'3'
' '
' '
'3'
'9'
'2'
'\n'
'1'
' '
'4'
' '
'5'
'2'
'3'
' '
'2'
'\n'
'2'
'\n'
'1'
'9'
'\n'
'2'
' '
'2'
'3'
'\n'
'2'
'\n'
'1'
'2'
' '
' '
'2'
'3'
'4'
' '
'2'
'3'
' '
' '
'2'
'3'
' '
' '
'3'
'9'
'\n'
'2'
'\n'
'1'
' '
'4'
' '
'5'
'2'
'3'
' '
'2'
'\n'
'2'
'\n'
'1'
'9'
'\n'
'2'
' '
'2'
'3'
' '
'2'
'\n'
```

Comment: Your code looks ok (apart from the confusing re-use of the name `reader`, and the overly-verbose `str.split(data)` instead of `data.split()`). I suspect that the problem is in the input file. I suggest you do a hexdump on it to make sure it really does contain what you think it does.

Comment: iterate over the file object `for line in data: `and `print(repr(line))`

Comment: @jamylak, `'2', '2', '19', '2'` does not make sense

Comment: ok you need to do a `data = reader.read().replace("\n","").split()`. you have newline chars between the digits

Comment: Thanks! That worked awesome. What was the reason it got the \n for ?

Comment: There could be many reasons depending on where the data came from originally . Anyway always use `repr `if you get output where you don't seem to get what you expect.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Good call on suggesting `repr()`; I guess not everyone is familiar &/or comfortable with doing a hexdump.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("filename") as f:
    rd=f.readlines()
    for x in rd:
        q=x.replace("\n","").split()
        print (sum(int(t) for t in q))
```

This one works. For the `replace()` and `\n` part check @ Padraic Cunningham's comments. Better if you used to use `with open()` method for file process.